# How to get only value without the index in select change method in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, select, ngfor

Here is my code in HTML.

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event)" 
[ngModel]="user" name="user" >              
<option *ngFor="let user of users async as users;" 
[ngValue]="user.userid">{{user.userName}} </option>                                                          
</select>
```

Here is my code in Component

```
onChange($event)
{

   this.userid = $event.target.value;
   console.log(this.userid);
}
```

When I log the value. Say the user has id - XYZ. 
It's being logged as

```
1: (Index of the selection)
XYZ
```

How do I get only value without the index?

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, this is how I do it:

```
 <select class="custom-select"
       id="carType" formControlName="selectOptionCarType"
                    #carType
     (change)="onSelectCarTypeValueChange(carType.value)">
              ....
  </select>
```

And then:

```
   onSelectCarTypeValueChange(value: string) {
      this.carType=value.split(":", 2)[1].trim());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `$event` to the `onChange()` to get the selected option value.
The `[ngModel]` of the Select-tag will hold that instance for you.
*I would rename the "user" model to `selectedUser` as that is more fitting.*

Try it like this

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="onChange()" 
[ngModel]="selectedUser" name="user" >              
    <option *ngFor="let user of users async as users;" 
    [ngValue]="user.userid">{{user.userName}} </option>                                                          
</select>
```

And in your component

```
export class YourComponent {
  selectedUser: User;

    onChange()
    {
       console.log(this.selectedUser);
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: `console.log(this.selectedUser)`

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Tried as you suggested. I'm getting undefined in log.

Comment: @Anirudh updated the answer. Don't forget to declare the property in your component